# How to tell whether invitation to special issue of a journal is worth being accepted?

Tags: journals, special-issue, invitations

I have been invited to participate to a special issue of [Entropy](https://www.mdpi.com/journal/entropy) for some work that I have done in statistical physics.

I received from other journals many such invitations which looked like spam,  and I wonder whether I should take this one more seriously, or consider it somehow a good one.

What are the criteria to tell whether the special issue is 'prestigious' enough, besides Impact Factor and names of guest editors?

Comment: Did the guest editor reach out to you specifically? Or did this feel like a spam email generated through data collected by a web crawler?

Comment: I don't know anything about the journal or its sponsor (mdpi.com) but you could probably learn if they are reputable or not (predatory). But in general, if you can trust the guest editors, and they have good professional standing, then you can probably trust the journal.

Comment: Have you ever cited a paper in _Entropy_?  Have you ever even **read** a paper in _Entropy_?  Do you recognize and trust the guest editors?

Comment: mdpi is good publisher, maybe also not so known for publications on fundamental science problems, rather technical and applied sciences and especially real-world applications. I also got several invitations from varying guest editors I know from conferences being leaders in their field. It looks like they have a strong growth strategy with many special issues. But when you can publish your results in a top-tier journal, I would always prefer over an special issue. But I quite often stumble over mdpi publications on google scholar looking for technical in-depth review articles.

Comment: @JWH2006 it looks like an automated email, but then I wrote back to ask for some additional information and they relied politely, copying the editor

Comment: @JeffE No, no and no.

Comment: In light of your responses to the comment of @JeffE, it sounds as though you are asking whether you should publish a paper in a journal you've barely heard of, as part of a special issue you don't have any direct connection to (i.e., it's not in honor of someone who influenced your work, it's not connected to a conference you attended, etc), which is being edited by people you don't know or even recognize by reputation. Seems pretty straightforward.

Comment: @James Then you've just answered your own question: No, no, and no.

Answer (score 3):

First things first, *Entropy* is an MDPI journal. MDPI is a rather controversial publisher - see the "Controversies section of [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MDPI) - and while I make no judgment on whether it's a predatory publisher, it's preferable to know the facts so you can make an educated decision on whether to publish with them.

If you conclude that it's worth publishing with them, then factors to consider are:

- Do you have anything relevant to contribute to the special issue?
- Do you know who the editors are? Are they authorities in your field?
- How good is the journal? Have you read/cited papers published in it? If not, you can still look at the papers in its current issues and draw your own conclusions about its quality.
- Which databases are the journal indexed in? This is usually a concern, but since you mention "impact factor", that means the journal is indexed by the Science Citation Index, and that's *the* index to be concerned about. If the journal is indexed there every other index doesn't really matter.
- How much is the article processing charge, and can you afford to pay it? MDPI is an open access publisher, so you can only publish OA with them, which usually means there's an APC. It's possible they're offering you free OA (this is especially likely if you're an invited submission, similar to how invited conference speakers often have the conference attendance fee waived). Otherwise they might simply be letting you know that you might be interested in this special issue, in which case you'll probably need to pay the APC.

But in the end the final decision is up to you. If you submit, acceptance is not guaranteed, although I'll venture that your chances are relatively good. If yours is an invited submission, then you might get to list that prominently on your CV; even if not, it's still +1 to your publication count. But preparing a submission will take time, and if you have nothing really worth publishing available, that might not be time well spent. It's up to you.

Answer (score 1):

Research libraries tend to have help pages that explain evaluating the credibility of journals. I'll link to the [Emory Health Sciences Library page](http://health.library.emory.edu/writing-publishing/quality-indicators/journal-credibility.html), since it has some credible steps that I'll paraphrase briefly:

- In what databases is the journal listed? (is it in the big databases for your field?)
- What is the publication history? (has it been around a long time? is it on a regular release schedule?)
- What is its review process? (peer reviewed? refereed? how long does review seem to take?)
- What is the journal's Impact Factor? (a measure of citation frequency)

Evaluating a journal with these questions require some expertise in your field, so you should do the work of answering those questions, and consult a research librarian or mentor if you have questions. In general, I'd see if I can find it in the main databases I use for research, if it keeps to a regular schedule (biyearly, quarterly, monthly), if you can find any clues to how long their review process takes, and so on.

You can also use tools in some databases to look up an article from the journal and see where it was cited. For instance, if you find an article in that journal, you can search for it on Google Scholar and see the number of times it has been cited with the search result. You can then see where the articles citing the journal are published -  do you know those journals? Are they reputable?

Comment: I find the first criterion ambiguous: it all comes down to the definition of "big database," which is not specified here, and thus ambiguous and potentially arbitrary .

Comment: Major database - for example, is the journal in one of the first three you would use to do research in your field? Yes, it is literally arbitrary - you are evaluating it based on your own standards. You set your standards.